# What route is called from multilple routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

How does a asp.net mvc routing choose what route to use from

```
[Route("{language}/Index-English", Name = "Index.EN")]
[Route("{language}/Index-German", Name = "Index.DE")]
[Route("{language}/Index-French", Name = "Index.FR")]
[Route("{language}/Index-Italian", Name = "Index.IT")]
public ActionResult Index(string language)
{
    return View();
}
```

I know that I can generate url based on route name, but in case I do not want to use it how can I generate a link using Url.Action that will call route Index.FR instead of Index.DE

Comment: Just curious, is using `Url.RouteUrl` instead of `Url.Action` bothering you that much?

Comment: No, just sometimes you are not able to mix this two if you are using a common header for example.